# Struts2 - How to write a template for six JSPs that are almost the same?

Tags: jakarta-ee, struts2, enums

I have six JSPs that are almost the same, the difference between them is that each one of them iterates over an enum that is splitted into its first attribute.

**The enum:**

```
public enum Segmento {

    INTERNACAO_DOMICILIAR(Vertical.1, "/relatorios/saude/tiss/internacao/domiciliar", "Interna&ccedil;&atilde;o Domiciliar", Projeto.TISS, Arrays.asList(LinksRelatorios.CAIXA_VISITA, LinksRelatorios.CAIXA_VISITA_EMPRESA, LinksRelatorios.PRODUTIVIDADE_INTERNACAO_DOMICILIAR, LinksRelatorios.PENDENCIAS, LinksRelatorios.SOLICITACAO_INICIAL, LinksRelatorios.SOLICITACAO_PRORROGACAO, LinksRelatorios.TEMPO_RESPOSTA)),
    INTERNACAO_CONCIERGE(Vertical.2, "/relatorios/saude/tiss/internacao/concierge", "Interna&ccedil;&atilde;o Concierge", Projeto.TISS, Arrays.asList(LinksRelatorios.INTERNACOES_CONCIERGE)),
    OPERADOR_WEB(Vertical.3, "/relatorios/saude/tiss/operadorweb", "Operador Web", Projeto.TISS, Arrays.asList(LinksRelatorios.ATENDIMENTO_ANALITICO, LinksRelatorios.ATENDIMENTO_SINTETICO, LinksRelatorios.TEMPO_ANALISE_ANALITICO, LinksRelatorios.TEMPO_ANALISE_SINTETICO, LinksRelatorios.SLA));

    private Vertical vertical;
    private String namespace;
    private String descricao;
    private Projeto projeto;
    private List<LinksRelatorios> links;

    private Segmento(final Vertical verticalParam, final String namespaceParam, final String descricaoParam,
            final Projeto projetoParam, final List<LinksRelatorios> linksParam) {
        this.vertical = verticalParam;
        this.namespace = namespaceParam;
        this.descricao = descricaoParam;
        this.projeto = projetoParam;
        this.links = linksParam;
    }

    public Vertical getVertical() {
        return this.vertical;
    }

    public String getNamespace() {
        return this.namespace;
    }

    public String getDescricao() {
        return this.descricao;
    }

    public Projeto getProjeto() {
        return this.projeto;
    }

    public List<LinksRelatorios> getLinks() {
        return this.links;
    }
}
```

**One of the six JSPs:**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<s:url value="/includes/js/botoes/links.js" />"></script>
</head>
<div class="menuBotoes">
    <s:iterator value="segmentosVerticalSaude" var="segmento">
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="tableBotaoMenu">
            <tr class="trCimaBotaoMenuSelect">
                <td align="center" class="imagemBotaoMenuSelect"><img src="<s:url value="/includes/imagens/global/botoes/grafico.png" />" /></td>
                <td align="left" class="descricaoBotaoMenuSelect"><s:property value="descricao" escapeHtml="false" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="trBaixoBotaoMenuSelect">
                <td align="center" class="imagemBotaoMenuSelect"><s:property value="projeto.sigla" escapeHtml="false" /></td>
                <td align="left" class="descricaoBotaoMenuSelect">
                    <select>
                        <option value="">-- Selecione um relat&oacute;rio --</option>
                        <s:iterator value="links" var="link">
                            <option value="<s:url namespace="%{#segmento.namespace}" action="%{#link.action}" />"><s:property value="textoLink" escapeHtml="false" /></option>
                        </s:iterator>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </s:iterator>
</div>
```

The difference among these JSPs is in the seventh line. I iterate over the enum that I described above, but each one of the JSPs iterate over a list that is created in my action that splits the enum per its first parameter, in other words, the first JSP will only bring the enum entries that the first attribute of it equals one, the second JSP will only bring the enum entries that the first attribute of it equals one and that goes on.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT: The actions that split the enum:**

```
public static List<Segmento> getSegmentosVerticalSaude() {
    return BaseAction.getSegmentosPorVertical(Vertical.SAUDE);
}

public static List<Segmento> getSegmentosVerticalAuto() {
    return BaseAction.getSegmentosPorVertical(Vertical.AUTOMOVEIS);
}

public static List<Segmento> getSegmentosVerticalCapitalizacao() {
    return BaseAction.getSegmentosPorVertical(Vertical.CAPITALIZACAO);
}

public static List<Segmento> getSegmentosVerticalDental() {
    return BaseAction.getSegmentosPorVertical(Vertical.DENTAL);
}

public static List<Segmento> getSegmentosVerticalPrevidencia() {
    return BaseAction.getSegmentosPorVertical(Vertical.PREVIDENCIA);
}

public static List<Segmento> getSegmentosVerticalResidencial() {
    return BaseAction.getSegmentosPorVertical(Vertical.RESIDENCIAL);
}

private static List<Segmento> getSegmentosPorVertical(final Vertical vertical) {
    final List<Segmento> segmentosSaude = new ArrayList<Segmento>();
    for (final Segmento segmento : Segmento.values()) {
        if (vertical == segmento.getVertical()) {
            segmentosSaude.add(segmento);
        }
    }

    return segmentosSaude;
}
```

Each one of these methods will be called in each one of the six JSPs. I want a way to know in runtime which one I should call.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. If the only thing that's different is the list being passed to the JSP then why would there need to be any more than the single JSP?

Comment: @DaveNewton how would I reference the correct list for each case? Sometimes the list is segmentosVerticalSaude, other times segmentosVerticalAuto, other times segmentosVerticalCap and etc...

Comment: Since you *do know* which JSP page to call, then use that knowledge to determine which list to pass to a single JSP and iterate that list. There is smell of overengineering all around the code btw... keep it as simple as possible, it will complicate by itself.

Comment: It's called that because *you're* calling it that. Call it the *same thing*. If *you* aren't the one calling it that, wrap it in something that gives it the same name, or create a custom tag, JSP-based, that you can pass the list into, or use `<s:set>`, and use that from each of the separate JSP pages.

Comment: Maybe I should add more code to be more clear about my problem.

Comment: @AndreaLigios that's how I'm doing. I pass the list to a single JSP, but I repeat this six times, if the enum grows to 200, I'll have 200 JSPs and that's what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: How many `.jsp` files (of that kind) do you have in your project ? The question is not clear at all :|

Comment: @AndreaLigios so far I have six, but this number will increase. What is not clear to you?

Comment: You must have one. What is not clear to you? :)

Comment: But that's what I'm trying to accomplish since the beggining of the question. I _do_ want to have only one JSP, I just don't know how I would reference the right method of my action in the JSP.

Comment: @Philippe In this case you tie the JSP to the action and should have multiple copies that depends on action specific code. Choose the common name if it used the same objects and set that name before return a result. I earlier days we put such things to request attributes.

Comment: @RomanC use the request is how I would do in Struts 1. I didn't want to do it, I think Struts 2 should have a more elegant approach, but I think this solution is what I'll code.

Comment: Then do it like putting a variable to the context and use that name in JSP whatever object it references.

Comment: For all of you that tried to help me: I used a parameter in the URL and I wrapped all those getSegmentoBy*Anything* methods into one that verifies the parameter and discover which Vertical to use. Thanks for your help, time and patience. According to SO rules, should I create an answer explaining myself or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @DaveNewton I wrapped all the getSegmentosPorVertical *Anything* into one single method that verifies a parameter passed in the URL and finds out which enum entry should use.

**The methods are now coded this way:**

```
public static List<Segmento> getSegmentos() {
    return BaseAction.getSegmentosPorVertical(Vertical.findVerticalByIdentificador(BaseAction
            .getParameter("vertical")));
}

private static List<Segmento> getSegmentosPorVertical(final Vertical vertical) {
    final List<Segmento> segmentos = new ArrayList<Segmento>();
    for (final Segmento segmento : Segmento.values()) {
        if (vertical == segmento.getVertical()) {
            segmentos.add(segmento);
        }
    }

    return segmentos;
}
```

**The original JSP is this way: (The only thing that changed here was the method call in the first struts taglib iterator)**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<s:url value="/includes/js/botoes/links.js" />"></script>
</head>
<div class="menuBotoes">
    <div align="right">
        <s:a namespace="/filtros/verticais" action="iniciarFiltroVerticais">
            <img src="<s:url value="/includes/imagens/global/botao-voltar.png" />" width="59" height="26" alt="Voltar para a tela de sele&ccedil;&atilde;o de relat&oacute;rios por verticais." />
        </s:a>
    </div>
    <s:iterator value="segmentos" var="segmento">
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="tableBotaoMenu">
            <tr class="trCimaBotaoMenuSelect">
                <td align="center" class="imagemBotaoMenuSelect"><img src="<s:url value="/includes/imagens/global/botoes/grafico.png" />" /></td>
                <td align="left" class="descricaoBotaoMenuSelect"><s:property value="descricao" escapeHtml="false" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="trBaixoBotaoMenuSelect">
                <td align="center" class="imagemBotaoMenuSelect"><s:property value="projeto.sigla" escapeHtml="false" /></td>
                <td align="left" class="descricaoBotaoMenuSelect">
                    <select>
                        <option value="">-- Selecione um relat&oacute;rio --</option>
                        <s:iterator value="links" var="link">
                            <option value="<s:url namespace="%{#segmento.namespace}" action="%{#link.action}" />"><s:property value="textoLink" escapeHtml="false" /></option>
                        </s:iterator>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </s:iterator>
    <div align="right" style="clear: both;">
        <s:a namespace="/filtros/verticais" action="iniciarFiltroVerticais">
            <img src="<s:url value="/includes/imagens/global/botao-voltar.png" />" width="59" height="26" alt="Voltar para a tela de sele&ccedil;&atilde;o de relat&oacute;rios por verticais." />
        </s:a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**The JSP that creates the parameter:**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<head></head>
<div class="menuBotoes">
    <s:iterator value="verticais" var="vertical">
        <s:a namespace="/filtros" action="iniciarFiltroSegmentos?vertical=%{#vertical.identificador}" cssClass="%{#vertical.classeCSSLink}">
            <span class="<s:property value="classeCSSSpan" />"><s:property value="textoLink" escapeHtml="false" /></span>
        </s:a>
    </s:iterator>
</div>
```

**And last but not least, the enum that holds the parameter value:**

```
public enum Vertical {

    SAUDE(1, "botoesMenu", "verticalSaude", "Sa&uacute;de"),
    AUTOMOVEIS(2, "botoesMenu disabled", "verticalAutomoveis", "Autom&oacute;veis"),
    CAPITALIZACAO(3, "botoesMenu disabled", "verticalCapitalizacao", "Capitaliza&ccedil;&atilde;o"),
    DENTAL(4, "botoesMenu disabled", "verticalDental", "Dental"),
    RESIDENCIAL(5, "botoesMenu disabled", "verticalResidencial", "Residencial"),
    PREVIDENCIA(6, "botoesMenu disabled", "verticalPrevidencia", "Previd&ecirc;ncia");

    private int identificador;
    private String classeCSSLink;
    private String classeCSSSpan;
    private String textoLink;

    private Vertical(final int identificadorParam, final String classeCSSLinkParam, final String classeCSSSpanParam,
            final String textoLinkParam) {
        this.identificador = identificadorParam;
        this.classeCSSLink = classeCSSLinkParam;
        this.classeCSSSpan = classeCSSSpanParam;
        this.textoLink = textoLinkParam;
    }

    public int getIdentificador() {
        return this.identificador;
    }

    public String getClasseCSSLink() {
        return this.classeCSSLink;
    }

    public String getClasseCSSSpan() {
        return this.classeCSSSpan;
    }

    public String getTextoLink() {
        return this.textoLink;
    }

    public static Vertical findVerticalByIdentificador(final int identificadorParam) {
        for (final Vertical vertical : Vertical.values()) {
            if (vertical.getIdentificador() == identificadorParam) {
                return vertical;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    public static Vertical findVerticalByIdentificador(final String identificadorParam) {
        if (StringUtils.isBlank(identificadorParam)) {
            return null;
        }

        return Vertical.findVerticalByIdentificador(Integer.parseInt(identificadorParam));
    }
}
```